# Perform operations on button values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, button, calculator, operation

I'm trying to make a calculator in JS and I'm searching for ways to add, subtract, multiply and divide button values. I've created a function to display the buttons but now I realize that that might not be necessary and I might need just one function which displays and does the operation.

HTML code:

```
        <div class="numbers">
            <button value="1" onclick="displayButtons(this)">1</button>
            <button value="2" onclick="displayButtons(this)">2</button>
            <button value="3" onclick="displayButtons(this)">3</button>
            <button value="4" onclick="displayButtons(this)">4</button> 
            <button value="=" id="calculate" onclick="performOperations(this)">=</button>
            **etc.**
        <div class="operations">
            <button value="+" onclick="displayButtons(this)" style="width: 2rem; top: 5rem;">+</button>
            <button value="-" onclick="displayButtons(this)" style="left: -6rem; top: 5rem;">-</button>
            **etc.**
```

JS code:

```
function displayButtons(button) {
    outputDiv.innerHTML += button.value
}

function performOperations(button) {

    var val = parseFloat(button.getAttribute("value"));
    var total = parseFloat(document.getElementById('output').getAttribute("value"));

    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = total + val;
}
```

That is my attempt to do addition the button values and I have the performOperations called on the "=" sign which currently displays NaN onclick. (I'm working on the addition first).
Any push in the right direction is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If the value of the `=` button is `=`, what exactly are you attempting to do with parsing it to Float and adding `=` to `total` ?

Comment: My suggestion is that you debug each line to see what is happening yourself.

Comment: You are right, the = value doesn't make sense. As for debugging, do you have any website or software recommendations which will help me debug it line by line? I only use Chrome Developer Tools.

Comment: Personally, I use console.log() for debugging.  When I question what the outcome of a line of code is, I will console.log() the result to verify if it's producing the result I expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that you can use one function to do all the work *but* it means that you have to mark up your HTML with classes and data-attributes.

In this example I've used [CSS grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid) to display the various calculator buttons. The "equals" and "clear" buttons have a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to help the function decide what operation to do.

```js
// Cache our elements and add an event listener
// to the button container. `handleClick` returns a
// new function that is called when the listener is fired
const output = document.querySelector('.output');
const buttons = document.querySelector('.buttons');
buttons.addEventListener('click', handleClick(), false);

function handleClick() {

  // Initialise the sum
  const sum = [];

  // Return the function that will be called
  // when a click event occurs
  return function(e) {

    // Because we're using event delegation (details
    // below) we need to check that the element that
    // was clicked was a button
    if (e.target.matches('.button')) {

      // Destructure the type from the dataset, and
      // the text content
      const { dataset: { type }, textContent } = e.target;

      // `switch` on the type
      switch (type) {

        // If it's equals evaluate the elements in
        // the array, and output it
        case 'equals': {
          output.textContent = eval(sum.join(''));
          break;
        }
        
        // Clear empties the array, and clears
        // the output
        case 'clear': {
          sum.length = 0;
          output.textContent = '';
          break;
        }
        
        // Otherwise add the textContent to
        // the array, and update the output
        default: {
          sum.push(textContent);
          output.textContent = sum.join(' ');
          break;
        }
      }
    }

  }

}
```

```css
.container{width:175px;}
.buttons {display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 40px);grid-gap:0.3em;}
.button {display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;background-color: #efefef; border: 1px solid #565656;padding: 0.5em;}
.button:not(.void):hover {background-color: #dfdfdf; cursor:pointer;}
.output {height: 20px; padding: 0.5em 0.2em;font-size: 1.2em;border:1px solid #565656;margin-bottom: 0.2em;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="output"></div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <div class="button">7</div>
    <div class="button">8</div>
    <div class="button">9</div>
    <div class="button">*</div>
    <div class="button">4</div>
    <div class="button">5</div>
    <div class="button">6</div>
    <div class="button">/</div>
    <div class="button">1</div>
    <div class="button">2</div>
    <div class="button">3</div>
    <div class="button">-</div>
    <div class="button">0</div>
    <div data-type="clear" class="button">C</div>
    <div data-type="equals" class="button">=</div>
    <div class="button">+</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Additional documentation

- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [Event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/)

Comment: Thank you for showing me the solution. What I'm surprised is that I had a code in mind which looked like:
 ```var answer = num1 + num2 ```
 ```return answer ``` Where are all the operations coming from? For instance the division or multiplication. Which part tackles that? Thank you!

Comment: @RebjaA. It all happens in the `eval` statement: `eval(sum.join('')`. When you click on a button its text content is added to an array whether its 1, 5, +, or *. When the equals button is clicked it joins up the array, evaluates the string, and then outputs it.

Comment: So the sum.join method kind of detects the operations symbols and performs the necessary operations? Am I correct? Sorry, I just want to make sure I understand the code.

Comment: Yeah, so if I click 1 then + then 1 then 0 the array will be `[ '1', '+', '1', '0' ]`. The `join` makes it `"1+10"`. And that expression is evaluated to `11`.

Comment: I see now. I'll look into the join method more since I didn't know it could do that. 
 Thank you so so much! I appreciate it a ton.